# Cannot connect to the database on the remote server

Tags: mysql, database, database-connection, connection-string

I have an application with Java trying to connect to MySQL database `myDatabase` stored on the server `RemoteServer.com` (just an example). I am trying to connect to it by specifiyng connection string, password and user. The connection string in my case looks like that:

```
jdbc:mysql://RemoteServer.com/myDatabase
```

However, I cannot connect to the database (the user and password is specified correctly). When I was working with the database locally, I could connect without any problems (`jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myDatabase`). I guess I have a problem in specifying the connection string, is it right? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It could be various things. Is the remote server Linux or windows host ? Is database running and listening to port 3306 on remove server ? What does telnet to port 3306 on remote server say ? Lot of times its firewalls that block access to that port. Check firewall (hardware and software).

Also did you intentionally miss db port in your connection string ?

Comment: I am quite new in those things, so I did not miss anything on purpose. How did I find out the database port?

Comment: connect to the database and run :: SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'PORT';  - This will let you know what port the database server is running on.

Comment: did you try doing this : jdbc:mysql://RemoteServer.com:3306/myDatabase

Comment: Check if the user you are connecting has proper privilege to access from outside database server.

Comment: I run the command you told me, the port is 3306. Then I tried to run jdbc:mysql://RemoteServer.com:3306/myDatabase, but still not connected. I have an access to this database via phpMyAdmin, can it be somehow helpful?

Comment: can you ping remoteserver.com from application server (is it resolving the server name properly). I am assuming both are different servers. Where is phpMyAdmin running ?

Comment: sorry, I do not understand the first sentence, what do you mean exactly? The server I am trying to connect to has its phpMyAdmin client installed so I can access it.

Comment: Alright, lets get to basics here. What operating systems is your database server running on ? What operating system does your application server is running on ?

Comment: I am working on Windows OS, and I have no ides on which OS is running the database server, can I somehow find it on phpMyAdmin?

Comment: Here is one way of knowing it, run this query on the database server :: SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'version_compile_os';

Comment: This is what we have - Application running on windows host and database server running on remote Debian based Linux host. Next thing I need to know is where is phpMyAdmin running ? One application windows host or your local machine ?

Comment: when I want to acces phpMyAdmin client, I have to type to the the url address: https://RemoteServer.com/ and then I just enter my username and password. I hope this is the kind of answer.

Comment: Perfect, so phpmyadmin is on remote server. This can be narrowed down to two issues. 1. Your user is limited to access the database from the database server only 2. Firewall blocking 3306 from outside the server. Solution for the first issue is create a user that can access database from outside the database server. Here is the command to create that user : CREATE USER 'appuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'appuserpassword'; GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'appuser'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;  - And try using this user to connect from application and let me know how it went.

Comment: I tried this, it however seems I do not have privileges to do that - #1227 - Access denied; you need the CREATE USER privilege for this operation

Comment: so, there is no solution for this?

Comment: Get to who ever controls this database instance and let them create a user for you who can access it from outside the server. Syntax for creating an user is as mentioned below :: CREATE USER 'appuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'appuserpass'; - change parameters accordingly. If you see I mentioned % symbol which indicates that this user can access the database server from any where. Hopefully this solves your issue, if not one last thing we need to look at is firewall.

Comment: Yeah and that is the problem ,it is a commercial server so I dont think anyone will be eager to do that for me, I even dont know who to ask. But thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention OS, but this applies no matter OS you just might need to adjust your commands. To expose MySQL to anything other than localhost you will have to have the following line uncommented in my.cnf and assigned to your computers IP address and not loopback

```
#Replace xxx with your IP Address 
    bind-address        = xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
    Or add a bind-address = 0.0.0.0 if you don't want to specify the IP
```

Then stop and restart MySQL with the new my.cnf entry. If you're on Linux then go to the terminal and enter the following command.

```
lsof -i -P | grep :3306
```

That should come back something like this with your actual IP in the xxx's

```
mysqld  1046  mysql  10u  IPv4  5203  0t0  TCP  xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3306 (LISTEN)
```

If the above statement returns correctly you will then be able to accept remote users. However for a remote user to connect with the correct priveleges you need to have that user created in both the localhost and '%' as in.

```
CREATE USER 'myuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypass';
CREATE USER 'myuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypass';
```

Then

```
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'myuser'@'localhost';
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'myuser'@'%';
```

If you don't have the same user created as above, when you logon locally you may inherit base localhost privileges and have access issues. If you want to restrict the access myuser has then you would need to read up on the GRANT statement syntax HERE If you get through all this and still have issues post some additional error output and the my.cnf appropriate lines.

If you still have connection issues after this it could be firewall or IPTABLES related. Just come back and post what has happened after you have defined the access and users correctly.